# Cannot change my Screen Brightness

Tags: brightness

though I am Pressing Brightness Keys on my laptop.The brightness is still not changing But Showing Change in Progress Bar of Brightness Setting.

Hardware Spec:

Intel Pentium Dual Core 2.1 GHz 64 bit Processor;

Intel HD3000 Graphic card;

2 GB ram 1333 MHz;

500 GB HDD Sata;

Model: Lenovo G580(2689);

Ubuntu 13.10 Updated Up to date

No problem if I get temporary Solutions...But Please help.

Comment: What drivers do your graphics cards have? Use `lspci -v`.

Comment: VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller

i have got A solution on Some where on Ask Ubuntu for Temporary. I have to do this every time when i Restart my Machine:


sudo su

echo 150 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness